# cplusplus program not working in visual studio code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I am starting c++ in visual studio code. I don't want to use coderunner. So I use task configure it while seeing the official documentation of visual studio code for c++. My file .exe is build successfully on pressing ctrl+shift+b. But on running it is saying it is not compatible with the windows you are running.
Please tell me how to fix this issue.

Comment: Please read [ask], [mre], and take the [tour].

Comment: What version of Windows are you running? (In the **CMD** shell, use the `ver` command and `echo %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%`.)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that appropriate configuration ( 32 bits or 64 bits) is selected for build. It should be the same as Windows OS on your computer to be able to run it.